# For loop optimisation with Java8

Tags: for-loop, foreach, java-8

How do achieve this with one line ?

I am currently trying to do this

Example :

```
{{"id" :"2", values: ["10","11", "12"]} , {"id" : "3", values : ["23"]}}
```

to

```
{{"id" :"2","value": "10"},{"id": "2","value":"11"},
 {"id" :"3","value":"23"} , {"id" : "2", "value":"12"}}
```

My java code is

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> attrMap = new HashMap<>();
//getAllData() & item.getValues() both returns List

getAllData().forEach(item - > {
    item.getValues().forEach(val - > {
        attrMap.computeIfAbsent(item.getId(), (k) - > 
        new ArrayList < > ()).add(val.getValue());
    });
});
```

How can i do it only 1 line ?

Comment: By removing the line-breaks ... ?

Comment: This question is kinda absurd. First of all the most important is REAL optimisation (time + data), the number of lines isjust for readability. When I see that some piece of code won'tchange anymore sometimes I remove line-breaks so i can scroll the code faster. But thats all.

Comment: I mean to say to avoid two foreach loop & do it with one foreach loop. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, ids are unique

Answer (score 5):

Since the IDs are unique, you can do it like

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> attrMap = getAllData().stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    item -> item.getId(),
    item -> item.getValues().stream().map(i->i.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

But, of course, this will still have the performance characteristics of two nested loops. It would support parallel processing, though, but I doubt that your data will be large enough to draw a benefit from parallel processing.

Further, note that the resulting map still structurally matches your first pattern,

> ```
> {{"id" :"2", values: ["10","11", "12"]} , {"id" : "3", values : ["23"]}}
> ```

you just converted `item` to an entry of the result `Map` and `val` to an element of a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your input like this:

```
static class Data {
    private final int id;

    private final List<Integer> values;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Integer> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public Data(int id, List<Integer> values) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

It could be done via:

```
 List<SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>> result = Arrays.asList(
           new Data(2, Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12)), 
           new Data(3, Arrays.asList(23)))
              .stream()
              .flatMap(d -> d.getValues().stream().map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(d.getId(), x)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result); // [2=10, 2=11, 2=12, 3=23]
```

I am collecting those to `Pair` or `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

Comment: Don't think this is much shorter than the code from the OP.

Comment: I mean to say to avoid two foreach loop & do it with one foreach loop. Is it possible?